# Copy an entire row (first copy A then B and then C) to another sheet in their specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names vertically consisting of 500+ rows on sheet1 as follow
Bill no (002, 003)       Name   (john, james )     Amount (455, 55)

whereas, I have a bill invoice shaped format on sheet2  and need to substitute the sheet 1 data on it.

the below vba code works perfectly for one particular row (A3:C3) but the problem im facing is that the list on sheet1 has 500 plus rows.

so kindly help me with an alternative where I can mouse click a random cell (A3) and the vba code copies the entire row (A3:C3) from sheet1 to sheet 2 to their respective places

```vb
Sub Macro13()

    'Macro13 Macro

    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(17, 3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("c4").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You can receive some help only if you accurately explain what you need accomplishing... Based on what should your code to be adapted. It looks primitive in terms of selecting, copying and pasting, but in order to be replace by something else more efficient, you should explain what your code should do, in order to process that "huge data"...

Comment: i have edited my question .. i hope if this is accurately explained  and hope u find me a solution as soon as possible. 
thanking you in anticipation

Comment: A little clearer, but I am still not sure that I understand which is your need... Firstly, the construction `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select` is strange. Don't you intend to copy in the cell situated four columns to right taking like reference the previous selection? I mean, don't you intend to refer at "G3" range? The same for `ActiveCell.Offset(17, 3).Range("A1").Select`. `Range("A1")` does not do anything... Don't you want selecting the range "J21"? I am asking this, because I will try avoiding select, copy and paste, which only consumes Excel resources...

Comment: So, the logic would be, let us say, for the row 10 (in "Sheet2"), the "A10" value should be copied in "C11" of "Sheet3, then "B10" should be copied in "G11" and "C10" should be copied in "J28". is this understanding correct? I would like to emphasize that **you should accurately describe what is to be done**... The "respective places" is a useless concept.

Comment: yes thats the concept ... can u help me with it ??

Comment: Yes, I can. But I am not sure if you select an empty cell the code must proceed in the same way. Since your answering frequency is not the appropriate  one, I am afraid that if I will wait for clarification, from this point of view, the coronavirus pandemia will be history... :) I will place an answer, supposing that you also copy the other two values, even if the selected cell (in A:A) is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub CopyCellsSpecificPlaces()
 Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, aC As Range
 
 Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
 Set sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
 Set aC = ActiveCell
 
 If (Not aC.Parent Is sh2) Or (aC.Column <> 1) Then
    MsgBox "You must run the code after selecting a cell in A:A column of ""Sheet1""...": Exit Sub
 End If
 sh3.cells(4, "C").Value = aC.Value
 sh3.cells(4, "G").Value = aC.Offset(0, 1).Value
 sh3.cells(21, "J").Value = aC.Offset(0, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: the cells in sheet 3 should be constant. "C4" "G4" and "J21".

Comment: @Malcolm Dias: What does "yes thats the concept" means? I will adapt/simplify the code to always return in the cells you are mentioning (now...).

Comment: @Malcolm Dias: Adapted the code. Does it do now what you need?

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the following code and modify as you want.

```
Sub Macro13()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Paste

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A5").Paste

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D18").Paste

End Sub
```